# Retrieve the src from a image

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the src in a specific image on my webpage. When I entered my code the output is an undefined error.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAttribute')**

**This is the HTML code**

```
<div class="team-member-image border-radius-5px overflow-hidden">
      <img class="abc" alt="" src="images/team01.jpg">
</div>
```

**This is the js**

```
`<script>
      var pic = document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[0].getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
      var src = pic.getAttribute('src');
      console.log(src);
</script>`
```

What can be the issue in this and how can I solve this.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[0]` is the image. You shouldn't add `.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]`

Comment: Your code would be correct if `abc` were the class of the div, not the image.

Comment: You could do `const pic=document.querySelector("img.abc")` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call once get element:

```
var pic = document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[0];
```